# Silverlight: Make all TextBoxes behave the same in one action

Tags: textbox, expression-blend, silverlight-5.0

I'm working with Silverlight, how can I force all my textboxes to trim all leading and trailing whitespaces from their Text property in one place, say App.xaml or something else?

I don't want to be setting an event handler for the GotFocus event every time I use a TextBox.

And I want to keep the ability to fully use xaml, for instance, If I create a new control that inherits from TextBox, then I'll loose the xaml ability to set things declaratively.

It could be with behaviors, a global setter, or whatever action that allows me to keep using xaml and affect all textboxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a behavior, but if I were you, I would create a new control that inherits from TextBox. You will not "lose xaml ability".

```
public class DerrivedTextBox : TextBox    
{   
    public DerrivedTextBox() : base()
    {
        this.TextChanged += DerrivedTextBox_TextChanged;
    }

    void DerrivedTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //TODO: Edit text here
    }
}
```